# Im trying to run an HTML file from VS Code and I'm getting an error: "Your file couldn’t be accessed, It may have been moved, edited, or deleted."

Tags: html, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

The file is just a simple Hello world HTML file. I have the file opened from Ubuntu so I'm not sure why the file cannot be found. I am new to coding and cant figure this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<head>
    <title>Hello HTML</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO! Can you explain what you have done to run your HTML file? has it renamed in the meantime? Have you tried the HTML preview extension?

Comment: Make sure you have saved the file.

Comment: Please don't tag Visual Studio for Visual Studio Code questions - They are very different

Comment: Can you provide additional details on what steps you are taking to open the file?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try to restart visual studio and right click on your *.html file
[Rigth Click then choose "Open with Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBVY3.png)

This should reassign the path to vscode

Or you should make sure the file is saved before doing this "control"